# Using an id returned from an insert in a with statement in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Say that you have the following table structure, that you like wikipedia have the identity and state of a page stored in different tables:

```
create table endUsers (
  uuid             UUID         primary key,
  created          timestamptz  default now()
);

create table endUserRevisions (
  id               bigserial    primary key,
  endUser          UUID         not null        references endUsers,
  modified         timestamptz  default now(),
  modifiedBy       UUID         not null        references portalUsers,
  name             text         not null,
  company          text         not null,
  email            text         not null
);

alter table endUsers add column
  latestRevision  bigint        not null        references endUserRevisions;
```

And that you then want to insert a completely new user into this database like:

```
with lastID as (
  insert into  endUserRevisions (endUser, name, company, email)
    values ('08e7882c-7596-43d1-b4cc-69f855210d72', 'a', 'b', 'c') returning id)
insert into endUsers (uuid, latestRevision)
  values ('08e7882c-7596-43d1-b4cc-69f855210d72', lastID);

-- or

with revision as (
  insert into  endUserRevisions (endUser, name, company, email)
    values ('08e7882c-7596-43d1-b4cc-69f855210d72', 'a', 'b', 'c') returning *)
insert into endUsers (uuid, latestRevision)
  values ('08e7882c-7596-43d1-b4cc-69f855210d72', revision.id);
```

Both these variants fail with either

> column "lastid" does not exist

or

> missing FROM-clause entry for table "last"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the fail is because each subquery is accessable to the surrounding context as a table, not as a plain value. In other words it must be accessed using a select statement like:

```
with revision as (
  insert into  endUserRevisions (endUser, name, company, email)
    values ('08e7882c-7596-43d1-b4cc-79f855210d76', 'a', 'b', 'c') returning id)
insert into endUsers (uuid, latestRevision)
 values ('08e7882c-7596-43d1-b4cc-79f855210d76', (select id from revision));

-- or

with revision as (                                                                                                    
  insert into  endUserRevisions (endUser, name, company, email)                                                       
    values ('08e7882c-7596-43d1-b4cc-79f855210d74', 'a', 'b', 'c') returning id)                                      
insert into endUsers (uuid, latestRevision)                                                                           
  select '08e7882c-7596-43d1-b4cc-79f855210d74', revision.id from revision;
```